# Поиск организаций в произвольной области

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-places-api

Нужно найти организации только в пределах области, которая ограничена на карте многоугольником. Но средствами JS API можно ограничить область поиска только [прямоугольником](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/#param-parameters.options.boundedBy).

Как вывести на карту только организации, внутри полигона?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этой задачи лучше использовать [HTTP API Поиска по организациям](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/?from=so):

1. Сначала нужно определить границы многоугольника, например, методом JS API `geometry.getBounds()`.
2. Эти границы нужно использовать при поиске в параметре bbox, чтобы ограничить область поиска.
3. Список результатов поиска нужно отфильтровать, оставив только те, которые входят в заданный многоугольник (см. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm).

[Вот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/2fg46ee7/)

Comment: Пример можно попробовать (если заработает) разместить прямо в сообщении по Ctrl+M